# What is the added security of “PermitRootLogin no” alone?

Tags: ssh, root

Referring to [this Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321427/permitrootlogin-no-in-sshd-config-doesnt-prevent-su):

The setting `PermitRootLogin no` alone does not prevent `su -` after logging in as a normal user.
As described in the referenced answer, there it is possible to prevent `su` with **additional**  measures.

The question arises, though, what does `PermitRootLogin no` **alone** achieve?

The only thing I can think of is some extra traceability:

- `ssh root@somehost` -- we don't know who attempted / logged in as root
- `ssh joe@somehost` `su -` -- we know it was joe who attempted to get root privileges

Are there any other benefits?

Answer (score 2):

> The setting PermitRootLogin no alone does not prevent su - after
> logging in as a normal user.

Your statement assumes that *any* system is configured in such way that *all* users in this system are allowed to use `sudo` and that *any* user is allowed to executed *any* command via `sudo`. This may be the case in some systems if administrators don't care about security. But if administrators do care, `sudo` is configured very fine grained, only *some* users are allowed to use *sudo*, and in via *sudo* they are allowed to execute only *some* commands. The number of users that are allowed to execute `su` via `sudo` will be kept as low as possible, and this `sudo` permission will be given for a relatively short period of time. In case of on premises server one would login locally as a root and give `sudo su` permission to some user. In case of remote or virtual server an administrator would give `sudo su` permission via corresponding remote control tool. After the work that required `su` permission is done, this permission would be revoked again.

Thus, if an attacker was able to log in via `ssh` using some non-root account, and this user has very limited permissions in `sudo`, or even no `sudo` permissions at all, then the potential problems will be usually relatively limited compared to what an attacker with root permission could do.

Answer (score 0):

One other small benefit is, that it increases the search space for brute force attacks for someone who does not know the user accounts used in the organisation.

There is only one account named *root* and you can find it on every unix-like system. The names of the other administrator accounts vary from organization to organization. Therefore you have to know nothing about the organization to try to brute force the root account, but you have to guess the name of the other accounts if you want to brute force them.

Granted, the added security is small, but you did not set a limit.

Comment: Can you expand on this? I mean, the only difference I see is that `root@...` is not valid, and the attacker does not know that